# ¿cómo habilitar los certificados SSL en Sylius con apache?

Tags: apache2, certificado-ssl, sylius

¡hola! buena noche, estoy usando Sylius por motivos académicos en ubuntu server 16.04 i386.
corro el servidor con apache2 y necesito habilitar la seguridad SSL para mi sitio pero
con apache y por lo que he investigado necesito varios archivos entre ellos unos con extensión
.crt pero no sé de dónde conseguirlo o cómo escribirlo y el portal de Sylius no brinda información
al respecto. soy nuevo en esto del e-commerce. espero puedan ayudarme; gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para usar un Certificado Digital seguro y de manera gratuito, puedes usar `Let's Encrypt` el cual te provee un certificado digital gratuito para tu dominio. Es recomendable que la IP publica de tu servidor esté asociado a dominio para usar `Let's Encrypt`. El certificado ssl dura por 90 días, para ello viene se tiene el utilitario Cerbot que automáticamente te renueva el certificado ssl, y funciona de esta manera por seguridad.

En el caso de apache sobre Ubuntu es sencillo configurar `Let's Encrypt`, esto se debe a ya se cuenta  con un utilitario para las distribuciones mas conocidos de Linux.

1. Documentación:
   [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/es/getting-started/)
2. Generar certificado ssl mediante Cerbot
   [Let's Encrypt Ubuntu Apache](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-apache)

Comment: seguí los pasos a como me sugiere la documentación de Certbot pero me da un error en la línea: "sudo snap install --classic certbot", dice algo referente a que no está disponible "en estable" pero si lo está en el siguiente canal: "edge snap install --edge certbot" pero también da error :)